# Jinja templating for Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a template that does the following to sudoers:

```
{% for a in  cde_admins  %}
User_Alias  CDEADMIN = {{ a }}
{% endfor %}
```

And I have the variables defined:

```
cde_admins:
  - foo
  - bar
```

I am looking for a way that I can iterate through the loop and add a `,` after foo. So it basically would look like this when i run Ansible:

```
User_Alias  CDEADMIN = foo, bar
```

I've tried a few things like adding a `join(",")` to the Jinja2 syntax but all that does is:

```
User_Alias  CDEADMIN = f,o,o
User_Alias  CDEADMIN = b,a,r
```

Can someone point in the right direction to make it so it just adds a comma to the end of `foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` filter, but on the original list, not on the items:

```
User_Alias CDEADMIN = {{ cde_admins|join(', ') }}
```

Only the above line, without the `for`-loop.